# Trying to use getInorderIterator but its not printing my tree InOrder

Tags: java, iteration, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, inorder

I created a binary search tree and I am able to add and remove to it but when i try to use the getInorderIterator method and print the tree it prints "TreePackage.BinaryTree$InorderIterator@2e817b38"

maybe im just calling the method the wrong way?

This is how i print it in my main class:

```
System.out.println("In-order: " + tree.getInorderIterator());
```

this is my implementation of getInorderIterator():

```
 public Iterator<T> getInorderIterator()
{
    return new InorderIterator();
}

private class InorderIterator implements Iterator<T>
    {
    private StackInterface<BinaryNode<T>> nodeStack;
    private BinaryNode<T> currentNode;

    public InorderIterator()
    {
        nodeStack = new LinkedStack<>();
        currentNode = root;
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        return !nodeStack.isEmpty() || (currentNode != null);
    }

    public T next() {
        BinaryNode<T> nextNode = null;

        while (currentNode != null) {
            nodeStack.push(currentNode);
            currentNode = currentNode.getLeftChild();
        }
        if (!nodeStack.isEmpty()) {
            nextNode = nodeStack.pop();
            assert nextNode != null;

            currentNode = nextNode.getRightChild();
        } else
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        return nextNode.getData();
    }
    public void remove()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're printing the iterator object itself. If you want to print every element of the tree, you need to **use** the iterator in a loop, and print every element it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

> ```
> System.out.println("In-order: " + tree.getInorderIterator());
> ```

... prints the (string value of) the iterator object itself.  If you want to print the tree elements then you must use the iterator to retrieve the elements, and print those.  For example,

```
for (Iterator<?> it = tree.getInorderIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

Comment: This helped me out! Thank you!